# PHP | Node server/request cycle

Tags: php, node.js, server

I have a couple years experience in programmin web apps, because of that I feel very strange by asking this, but lately I'm having a serious doubt about php/node server/request cycle.

How the PHP/node server renders/build itself? It's on every  request or it builds/deploy only once and receive requests after that without rebuilding/running core code every time?

Example:

Browser request -> hits server > pass through kernel/core building code -> estabilish routes -> pass request to route -> return response -> end

OR

Deploy ONCE (pass through kernel/core building code) -> build routes -> waits for future requests indefinetely -> browser request -> hits server -> pass request to route -> return response -> end -> server still running and waiting for future requests

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP server is building once per request so if your website hits 300 requests in one time, PHP will fire 300 times. Node.js works differently - you start one application which works all time and each request just is another *thread (coroutine? I am not sure how this is named in Javascript, just JS is async)*.

Comment: That's why I was so confused, they work differently. First I worked only with php, now learning node and express I got so confused by this. Thanks for your explanation!